# How to disable detailed view of running epoch in pycharm and make it show less detail about running epoch?

Tags: deep-learning, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am newbie for deep learning and I have installed jupyter notebook as well as pycharm for writing and compiling my codes..As you can see in picture attatchment jupyter notebook and pycharm open.

My question is "Can I change view of running epoch in pycharm to less detailed view as it is been showing in jupyter notebook?"

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clearer what your problem is, and put the code in text form, not as an image.

Comment: the problem is not related to code , it is about view setting of pycharm . i want to make pychrm show running epoch vies as it is shown in jupyter notebook